# UDP Scanner protocol with AsyncTaskLoader in Android

Tags: android, udp, asynctaskloader

I'm working on my first Android app. The application shall scan for devices on the network using a proprietary protocol based on UDP broadcast. The protocol can send a discover message and receive responses from all available devices. Later on it can send a configuration command to a selected device to set network settings such as IP address etc. I have built an activity to display a list of found modules and I use AsyncTaskLoader to load devices to the list and that works fine.

My problem now is how I shall implement the UDP protocol and access it from the AsyncTaskLoader.

Shall I implement the UDP protocol as a service with one transmit and one receive thread? How do I interact with this thread from the AsyncTaskLoader in this case?

Any other ideas how I should design this?

Thanks, Jonas.